# MySQL Routines Not Showing in Workbench Object Browser

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I recently had to reinstall MySQL. After doing so and restoring databases, I find that in one of my databases that the routines are not displaying in the object browser of Workbench. If I issue select * from mysql.proc in the query window, I do see all the routines. Also, my application that uses the routines has no problem running and accessing. I just can't see them any longer from the object browser in Workbench. I do see the routines of other databases but just one database is giving me the problem. Any suggestions on the problem here?

Comment: A permission problem?

Comment: Could very well be. I see in Workbench that root user has no schema privileges. If I try to grant privileges to other users I get access denied for user root using password. I have tried several solutions to solve, but nothing is working for me at the moment. Not sure how to proceed at this point.

Comment: I fixed my root access denied error, but still not seeing the routines in Workbench object browser. I can only see them by accessing mysql.proc table directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest version of MySQL and the routines now are showing again.